# How can i unlink a branch from a git repository?

Tags: git

I want to directly push contents to a new repository.

Currently, content is present in one of the branches of an existing repository.
I already tried `git remote remove origin`.
But when I type `git branch`, It is showing the previous existing branch. Need Help.

Comment: What do you mean by "showing the previous existing branch`? A removing a remote won't change the state of a local branch.

Comment: Ohh...Thanks for answering. I am getting hang of git. So connecting it with new remote repository should work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "should work"? What do you expect it to do? What's wrong with the current branch?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to directly push contents to a new repository

Follow these steps:

1. Create new repository
2. Add the new repository as new remote
3. push your desired branch to the new remote
4. (optional) Delete the branch from the first remote

---

```sh
# 1. Create new repository
#    Under your git server create new repository

# 2. Add the new repository as new remote
git remote add remote2 <url>

# 3. Push your desired branch to the new remote
git push origin2 <branch name>

# 4. OPTIONAL
#    delete the branch from the first remote
git push origin :<branch name>
```